# Front End Dropdown Showing All Custom Post Type 'Agent'

Tags: custom-post-types, dropdown

Title says it all, I pretty much just want to put a dropdown list on the front end that will list all the posts of custom post type 'agent', preferably in alphabetical order, and go to that post when user clicks on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
//first get all agents
$agents = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'agent', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'title'));
//then just print out the dropdown:
if ($agents->have_posts()){
    echo '<select id="agent">';
    while ($agents->have_posts()){
        $agents-the_post();
        echo '<option value="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.get_the_title($post->ID).'</option>';
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        var dropdown = document.getElementById("agent");
        function onCatChange() {
            if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 ) {
                location.href = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
            }
        }
        dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
    -->
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: It appears that loading 77 posts like this takes too long or something is not quite right with the script, when I add this to the page it seems to attempt to load all the names, but all I get is a narrow dropdown with empty data and a scrollbar. I tried removing the js in case, but had no affect. Check it out here, test.medialayer.net, it's the second dropdown under find and agent.

Comment: @Chuck 77 posts should be that bad and you can always save the output as a `transient` , can you create a pastebin of the exact code you are using?

Comment: here is my pastebin. pastebin.com/n2CeVYrx Thanks.

Comment: I deleted that last comment with the pastebin, as I realized I was doing it completely wrong I have a new pastebin, pastebin.com/X4fDHwvL which is as far as I've gotten so far, if you have a moment to take a look and at least let me know if I'm going the right direction I would be grateful.

Comment: I'LL take a look as soon as get home

Comment: @Chuck: the latest pastebin you posted makes more sense and i just check the code i posted with a different post type and it worked just fine so i'm not sure what causes the problem in your page.

Comment: Thanks for checking, I just tried your code with a different post type and got the same results, I also tried the code on a page with everything else removed, and still had the same issue. Could it be something about the way that I have made my cpt? pastebin.com/iGH3eT3d  Thanks again.